# keytool: command not found

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to generate an application to put in the play store when I do this command:

```
Keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

This message is appearing `keytool:` command not found

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: solution worked for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change directory to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin` and then run your `keytool` command.

Or

Set the `PATH variable` permanently (Windows)

1. Click Start, then Control Panel, then System.
2. Click Advanced, then Environment Variables.
3. Add the location of the bin folder of the JDK installation for the
       PATH variable in System Variables. The following is a typical value
       for the PATH variable:

   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. It was the room variable even though it was in trouble. @swapnil-patwa

Comment: Great @lucas Santos :)

Comment: Note that you may need to change `jdk1.8.0_66` to the version of your `jdk` that you will usually find in `C:\Program Files\Java\` folder.

Also, you should close and reopen your terminal after making this change.